# Castle Windsor 3.0 Different services with same names -- how?

Tags: c#, .net, castle-windsor, ioc-container

Suppose, I have two interfaces IFirst and ISecond, both with several implementations, e.g. FirstClassForMe, FirstClassForYou, SecondClassForMe, SecondClassForYou.

I want to register them in IoC container (no matter which lifestyle):

```
this.container.Register(
    Component.For<IFirst>().ImplementedBy<FirstClassForMe>().Named("Me"),
    Component.For<IFirst>().ImplementedBy<FirstClassForYou().Named("You"), 
    Component.For<ISecond>().ImplementedBy<SecondClassForMe>).Named("Me"),
    Component.For<ISecond>().ImplementedBy<SecondClassForYou>().Named("You"))
```

I want to use this as follows:

```
var forWho = this.GetCode();
var first = this.Container.Resolve<IFirst>(forWho);
var second = this.Container.Resolve<ISecond>(forWho);
this.Work(first, second);
```

But in windsor, I get an ComponentRegistrationException

> Component Me could not be registered. There is already a component with that name. Did you want to modify the existing component instead? If not, make sure you specify a unique name.

However, I believe, it is possible to resolve this dependency, as far as pairs (interface; code) are unique, for each registration. Is it possible to make windsor work according to this scenario? E.g. to find all registrations for IFirst, and then select one by name.

Answer (score -1):

Windsor's [Service Overrides](http://docs.castleproject.org/Windsor.Registering-components-one-by-one.ashx#Supplying_the_component_for_a_dependency_to_use_Service_override_9) would work for what you'd like to do.

Comment: Can You please elaborate on this, as far as I don't see how service overrides could help?

Comment: After re-reading, it sounds like you want to resolved your component based on some "Value" that is determined at runtime?  Would something like this work for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8941055/setting-the-name-property-during-registration-of-a-component-using-castle-windso/8954362

Comment: I have posted a reply in question You mentioned. What I currently use is described there, and the error I am stuck with described there too, in last sentence of my answer.

Comment: I am sure Your approach will work for me, but it looks too _complicated_ for this simple task, and I will think about this for day or two =)